# Can Still Life photography have framing?

Tags: composition, landscape, still-life, framing

Can a still life image have framing in it or is framing usually found in landscape photography?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please post some example images.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Framing is a technique in composition where objects in the photo direct the viewers attention by covering (usually) one or more edges, creating a sort of frame-within-the-frame. In landscape photography, this is usually foreground trees or rocks — but it doesn't have to be. It could be a building, or even *people*. In Raphael's *Sistine Madonna*, the figures to the left and right and the cherubs below (more famous than the whole!) *frame* the subject — mother and child

[image: public domain]

This, of course, is no still life, but it illustrates the principle: framing isn't restricted to landscapes.

In a still life, framing might include cloth drapery, the edge of a table, a doorway... any element that isn't part of the main subject but serves as, well, a framing device for it.

This example (*The Juice of Life*, CC-BY-SA [Esther Spektor](https://www.flickr.com/photos/41890366@N03/5645121648/)) demonstrates this — here, the curtain and the edge of the window provide framing for the arrangement on the table.

[image: The Juice of Life, CC-BY-SA Esther Spektor]

Of course, here it's somewhat subtle and the framing objects are not in the foreground; a more overt use of framing might be looking through an open window, where the window's literal frame would serve as framing in this sense, too.

("Framing" also has a different sense, the relationship of the entire photograph's rectangular frame to all visible elements — in that sense, of course, *all* photographs exhibit framing.)